# Disable NDR for DLs in O365 hybrid deployment

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

Is there a way to disable the delivery of NDRs when emailing a larger internal DL? Some of users are on O365 and some are on on-prem exchange.

There are methods for on-prem exchange but I can’t find anything for hybrid or cloud.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Exchange server or Exchange Online services, we can only disable non-delivery reports to the remote domain.

Configure remote domain message reporting

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649325(v=exchg.150).aspx

Remote domains in Exchange Online

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj966211(v=exchg.150).aspx